# Grid of squares to fit its parent

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I need to create a responsive grid of squares. My grid is inside its parent, which is also responsive. I'd like my grid to fit perfectly inside its parent. I don't know how to achieve it and still use square cells.

I know the trick with `padding-bottom: 100%` to make elements square, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. Also, I can't just calculate the percentage for the cells, as the number of cells can change.

Here's what I have:

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff8;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
}

.grid > * {
    background-color: orange;
}

.grid > *::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
        <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the images to better describe my goal:

[image: Horizontal Grid]

[image: Vertical Grid]

Can it even be done?

Comment: it seems you already did it, no? I only see vertical alignment missing

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope, I hardcoded the width and height for the cells to make the screenshots :) The images reflect my goal, the code attached doesn't produce this effect.

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @TemaniAfif how come? I just have to fit the grid of squares (the grid doesn't wrap) to a parent of certain size. I think it's not as simple as it sounds, or I'm missing something. It's a React app, so my grid needs to scale properly for any number of squares horizontally and vertically, plus for any size of the parent. The cells need to be squares.

Comment: @RoboRobok yeah, this is definitely a tough one. Is there anything in the grid items, or simply a solid color using the `padding-top: 100%` trick? I've been trying to crack at different ways this can happen. It's tricky.

Comment: Actually all of the cells are empty, as I'm making the cells the actual content. They are simple circles. In worst case, I will just calculate percentage dynamically, using the ratio of width and height and use gap as well in my calculation. It's gonna be a bit hackish, but would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the container to a `flex` parent, and then `align-items` for the `grid` parent.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #ff8;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid>* {
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.grid>*::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 800px;
  background: #ff8;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container2 .grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly for horizontal container. Please try with `width: 1000px`.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. Let me see if there is a way to fix that.

Comment: Have you found something? :)

Comment: I haven't. I'm going to leave this answer here in the event I do and can update it. Certainly a challenge!

Comment: Thanks, please let me know if something comes up.

Comment: @RoboRobok I was sipping my coffee, and think I found that this may not be possible using CSS alone. Mostly because the explicit height on the `.container`. If that was set to `min-height`, this would work since the container could actually be adjusted vertically by the content, no matter the column or row count. Not sure if that's an option for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @disinfor is correct but if you don't want to use the flex display and keep grid display, have you tried to add a percent `padding-top`?

I added also a padding-bottom to fix the problem when `width: 1000px`

```css
.container {
    width: 1000px
    height: 300px;
    background: #ff8;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.grid {
    padding-top: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
}

.grid > * {
    background-color: orange;
}

.grid > *::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
        <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, however disinfor's answer doesn't fully work, please take a look at my comment below it.

Comment: @RoboRobok I added also a padding-bottom to fix the problem when width: 1000px. Try now and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Why 15%? It needs to work for any number of rows, columns and parent width and height :(

Comment: It's just an example @RoboRobok, now you can adjust this number

Comment: Like I said in the question, I can't just "adjust that number", because it's a React app and it's all dynamic.